# Using instanceof to test for base class of a React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

To support nested navigation menu's, we're using React.cloneElement to add properties to child menu components (the menu components are custom components, based on react-bootstrap). To prevent that we're cloning all elements even though they are not child menu components, but regular content components, I want make the cloning conditional.

All menu components are sub classes of 'MenuBase' (which itself is a sub class of React.Component). In my code, I tried to test whether a child of a react component (reading this.props.children by use of the React.Children utility functions) is an instance of MenuBase.

Simplified code:

```
interface IMenuBaseProps {
  // menu related properties
}

abstract class MenuBase<P extends IMenuBaseProps, S> extends React.Component<P, S> {
  // constructor etc.
}

interface IGeneralMenuProps extends IMenuBaseProps {
  // additional properties
}

class GeneralMenu extends MenuBase<IGeneralMenuProps, {}> {
  public render(): JSX.Element {
    // do some magic
  }
}
```

Somewhere in the menu logic I want to do something like the following

```
React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child: React.ReactElement<any>): React.ReactElement<any> ==> {
  if (child instanceof MenuBase) {
    // return clone of child with additional properties
  } else {
    // return child
  }
}
```

However, this test never results in true and as a result a clone is never made.

In the Chrome developer tools I can see that:

1. child.type = function GeneralMenu(props)
2. child.type.prototype = MenuBase

[image: typescript child watch]

Can somebody help me to clarify the following:

1. Why is instanceof not working
2. If I'm not able to use instance of the test for something in the inheritance chain of react components, what are my alternatives (I know I can test for the existence of one of the properties of IMenuBaseProps, but I don't really like that solution).

Comment: MenuBase doesn't extend `React.ReactElement<any>`

Comment: MenuBase extends ComponentBase which in turn extends ReactComponent (not in the simplified version, but in the real code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution of @NitzanTomer did not seem to work under all circumstances. I was not able to find the cause of the difference in test results on his machine and my machine.

Finally I found the following solution:

```
public render(): JSX.Element {
    // Iterate over children and test for inheritance from ComponentBase
    let results: JSX.Element[] = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child: React.ReactElement<any>, index: number): JSX.Element => {
        let isComponent: boolean = typeof child.type !== 'string' && React.Component.prototype.isPrototypeOf((child.type as any).prototype);
        let result: boolean = isComponent ? (child.type as any).prototype instanceof ComponentBase : false; // Not a component, then never a ComponentBase
        return <li>
                <div>Child nr. {index} is a React component: {isComponent ? "True" : "False"}</div>
                <div>And is a sub class of ComponentBase: {result ? "True" : "False"} { result !== this.props.expectedTestResult ? "(unexpected)" : ""}</div>
            </li>;
    })

    return (
        <ul>
            {results}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

In this solution, first a test is executed to check if the child is a React component. After that, 'instanceof' is used to determine whether the child component is a sub class of 'ComponentBase' (direct or indirect).

Because in TypeScript the 'type' property of React.Component does not have a 'prototype' property a cast to 'any' is necessary.

Comment: Where does ComponentBase come from??

Comment: There is no definition for `ComponentBase`??

Comment: Incomplete. Where's ComponentBase imported/defined?

Answer (score 9):

Looking at the [definition file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/react.d.ts), the [ReactChildren.map](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/react.d.ts#L2309) is defined like this:

```
map<T>(children: ReactNode, fn: (child: ReactChild, index: number) => T): T[];
```

This [ReactChild](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/react.d.ts#L89) is then defined like this:

```
type ReactChild = ReactElement<any> | ReactText;
```

In your case it's probably [ReactElement](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/react.d.ts#L25) which is:

```
interface ReactElement<P> {
    type: string | ComponentClass<P> | SFC<P>;
    props: P;
    key?: Key;
}
```

Your `MenuBase` is the `type`, so it probably should be:

```
React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child: React.ReactElement<any>): React.ReactElement<any> ==> {
    if (child.type === MenuBase) {
        // return clone of child with additional properties
    } else {
        // return child
    }
}
```

It seems that the `child.type` is the class of the component and not the instance and so instead of doing `child.type instanceof MenuBase` you need to do `child.type === MenuBase`.

---

#### Edit

After playing around with things I came up with this solution:

```
React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child: React.ReactElement<any>): React.ReactElement<any> ==> {
    if (MenuBase.isPrototypeOf(child.type)) {
        // return clone of child with additional properties
    } else {
        // return child
    }
}
```

If you'll want to check if the `child` is `GeneralMenu` then you'll need to do:

```
child.type.prototype === GeneralMenu.prototype
```

Comment: Unfortunately you suggestion doesn't work for two reasons: 1) child.type actually is not the type of the base class, but of the child itself (can be GeneralMenu) and 2) Before being able to use this test, you must cast 'child.type' to 'any' (but that's not really a problem).

Comment: Ok, so just use `child.type instanceof MenuBase`, that should be fine

Comment: This is not working either. I added an image of the watch of one of the 'child' objects in the developer tools. Naming is a bit different from my simplified example, but is explained.

Comment: @BjörnBoxstart Sorry that it took so long, only had time to look into it now, but I believe I found a solution for your problem. Check my revised answer.

Comment: This doesn't work either. It seems that React (Component) is disturbing the results of the tests that normally would apply.

Comment: If it were C# I could imagine that this test is not working, because MenuBase is a generic type, but I really don't know if that is the same reason why it is not working in TypeScript (which is translated into JavaScript without generics).

Comment: Weird, it worked for me when I implemented a similar scenario myself. The bottom line is that the `child.type` is a function, but it has the prototype of the component class of the actual child.

Comment: I would expect it to work, because the situation that you describe corresponds with the information in my screen dump of the developer tools, but the test still returns 'false'.

Comment: You're testing `MenuBase.isPrototypeOf(child.type)`?

Comment: Yes, exactly that...Could the conversion from TypeScript to Javascript (ES5) be of any influence? In TypeScript I'm subclassing all my components from React.Component (MenuBase also is a sub class from React.Component). I have some difficulties with executing the test in the console, because at that time it says 'Uncaught ReferenceError: MenuBase is not defined(...).

Comment: The compilation shouldn't mess things up, and as I said, I managed to get it work this way. Can you maybe create a small example that illustrates this problem and then share it with me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123170/discussion-between-bjorn-boxstart-and-nitzan-tomer).

Comment: After exchanging example code with @NitzanTomer, it appeared that in my environment his suggested test resulted in 'false', but in his environment it resulted in 'true'. Finally I found a working solution (see accepted answer).