# React children issue (typescript)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, children

I will provide all the code needed for my issue, I am stumped as to how to solve this I have tried many things none of which worked.

```
export class JobBuilderOptimise extends React.Component<JobBuilderOptimiseProps & JobBuilderOptimiseDispatch> {
    render() {
        const {
            jobPosting,
            search,
            previewByTemplate
        } = this.props.pageState;


        return (

            <div className="optimise-page">
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={7} >
                        <div className="optimise-panel">
                            {this.props.children}
                        </div>
                    </Col>

                    <Col sm={5}>
                        <div className="preview-panel">
                            <JobPostingControl jobDescription={jobPosting.data} isLoading={search.previewRequestState.isBusy || previewByTemplate.isBusy} leftSide={this.props.children}/>
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

this.props.children either displays JobBuilderModel.tsx or JobBuilderSearch.tsx. I can provide the code for each if neccessary but the main identifying factors I can find are the props:

```
interface JobBuilderModelProps {
    pageState: BuilderState;    
}
```

---

```
interface JobBuilderSearchProps {
    pageState: SearchState;
}
```

and also the classNames of the container divs:

```
<div className="search-job-section">
...
</div>
```

---

```
<div className="model-job-section">
...
</div>
```

The reason I have provided these are because I have to figure out which of the two react components will be displayed (and I have been trying to distinguish the two in any way in order to identify which actually is being displayed but maybe that is not the right way to go about it), and based on that, have to pass a string into the JobPostingControl control that is also on the page. Let me know if any more details are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly the problem is how to find out what type of component is inside children of the `JobBuilderOptimise` component. If so - you can use `type` property of the child - that will return you type of the respective child.

Then you can test to see what inside to the code similar to:

```
if((child.type as any).prototype instanceof JobBuilderModel)
{

}
```

Comment: This works, thank you! I was wondering why .prototype is required here because isnt .type enough to give the type? Much appreciated

Comment: It might not work if your compile target of typescript is ES5 or lower. There is some discussion about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39387405/using-instanceof-to-test-for-base-class-of-a-react-component